# FormControlProps.isInvalid?: boolean | undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form using the React-Bootstrap form with formik and Yup for validation. I am getting typescript errors in invalid props, `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean undefined'.ts(2322)`. Here is my code,

This is my formik,

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      language: "",
      code: "",
    },
    validationSchema : PostSchema,
    onSubmit: (values: Post, { resetForm }) => {
      dispatch(createPost(values));
    },
  });
```

This is my form,

```
<Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group controlId="title">
    <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
      <Form.Control
       type="text"
       placeholder="Enter title"
       value={formik.values.title}
       onChange={formik.handleChange}
       isInvalid={formik.errors.title}
       />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {formik.errors.title}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
   </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="pt-3" controlId="description">
          <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
          <Form.Control
            style={{ height: "100px" }}
            as="textarea"
            placeholder="Enter Code description"
            value={formik.values.description}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            isInvalid={formik.errors.desc}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
          {formik.errors.description}
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
        <Form.Group className="mt-3" controlId="language">
          <FormLabel>Select Language</FormLabel>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            isInvalid={formik.errors.language}
          >
            <option value="">Select Any language</option>
            {allLang.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option key={item._id} value={item.language}>
                  {item.language}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </Form.Control>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {formik.errors.language}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="pt-3 mb-3" controlId="code">
          <FormLabel>Code</FormLabel>
          <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            style={{ height: "200px" }}
            placeholder="Enter Code"
            value={formik.values.code}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            isInvalid={formik.errors.code}
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {formik.errors.code}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Save Snippet
        </Button>
      </Form>
```

Here is my schema and interface,

```
export interface Post {
  _id?: string;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  language?: string;
  code?: string;
  userId?: string;
}

export const PostSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  title: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  description: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  language: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  code: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});
```

If I am commenting out `invalid` prop, everything is working fine but validation message is not appearing, it is basically saying, `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322) FormControl.d.ts(18, 5): The expected type comes from property 'isInvalid' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>, HTMLTextAreaElement>, "key" | keyof TextareaHTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, BsPrefixProps<...> & FormControlProps> & BsPrefixProps<...> & FormControlProps & { ...; }'`

Answer (score 0):

`isInvalid` is expecting a `boolean` or `undefined`.

In your code, you're passing in a possible string value or undefined.

```
 <Form.Control
   type="text"
   placeholder="Enter title"
   value={formik.values.title}
   onChange={formik.handleChange}
   isInvalid={formik.errors.title}
 />
```

In your code, `formik.errors.title` is returning a string value, or undefined when there is no error. That's why you're getting the typescript error.

A quick solution is probably like this

```
isInvalid={formik.errors.title ? true: undefined}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the type compatibility wrap the expression with `Boolean`. And also, better to check the `touched` state:

```
isInvalid={Boolean(formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title)}
```